# SDL Animated Sprite

Tags: c++, animation, sdl

I am trying to create a simple platformer game in C++ with SDL, although am having trouble implementing animated sprites into the game. Linked is my git repo.

As you will see i'm currently having difficult trying to draw a single portion of the sprite sheet as the player sprite and looping through it to animate it. At the moment the entire sprite sheet that contains the player sprites is being squished into a 32 pixel rectangle. I have looked into SDL_RenderCopy although changing the variables that I pass to the method has no affect.

https://github.com/mountainfolks/Platformer_SDL

Answer (score 0):

Have you stepped through your code to see which draw call you're hitting? `AnimatedSprite` inherits from `Sprite`, but you don't have `Draw` set as `virtual` in the base class, so you're actually calling `Sprite::Draw`. That would explain the behavior that points to the source rectangle being `null`.

Comment: thanks alot for the help, that was part of the reason why it was failing, but also because the rectangles for my method for rendercopy were getting the wrong variables. Thank you :)